# Any alternatives to Quicken with auto download of transactions?

Tags: software-recommendation

Quicken for Mac continues to suck, so I'm wondering if there are any viable alternatives.

I've tried a few, but none of them are able to automatically download activity from banks ("Direct Connect"). Yes, you can manually download an OFX/QFX from the bank's website, but I want the app to pull down the data without me having to go to a browser.

**[gnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/)** seems to [theoretically be able to do it](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Setting_up_OFXDirectConnect_in_GnuCash_2), but it's incredibly complicated, ugly, and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Did you search for "OFX" in the Mac App Store already?

Comment: @patrix Yes, but nothing comparable in there.

Comment: I've tried several as well, and none of them have met my needs.  I run Quicken for Windows in a VM.  It's more fully-featured and less error-prone, in my experience. :/